# fetch data from '/'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch

i was following tutorial about react and node together and in every tutorial  they are using something like

```
app.get('/api/blahblah', (req, res)=>{
  res.send('something')
})
```

and then they were fetching "something" from api/blahblah and getting that "something" in default route ('/')
 so i tried to send that something to "/" and fetch data from "/" but it did not worked 
and gave me this error

> Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

i am currently using this code:

***REACT***:

```
// Fetch the list on first mount
componentDidMount() {
 this.getList();
}

// Retrieves the list of items from the Express app
getList = () => {
fetch('/main')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(list => this.setState({ list }))
}
```

***NodeJS***

```
app.get('/main', (req,res) => {
var list = ["itdemfs1", "item2", "item3"];
res.json(list);
console.log('Sent list of items');
});
```

and code that is not working

```
 ***REACT***:

// Fetch the list on first mount
componentDidMount() {
 this.getList();
}

// Retrieves the list of items from the Express app
getList = () => {
fetch('/')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(list => this.setState({ list }))
}
```

***NodeJS***

```
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
var list = ["itdemfs1", "item2", "item3"];
res.json(list);
console.log('Sent list of items');
});
```

Comment: you might have to set a proxy on your react package.json. going to ses if i can provide a helpful answer.

Comment: `console.log(res)` and tell us what u get, u may have to take a snapshot.

Comment: i've got proxy already in my package.json

Comment: i've logged it before and guess what: it logged the html page code (whole)

Answer (score 0):

Since in React you fetch from **"/"**, what if you change your NodeJS to

```
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  var list = ["itdemfs1", "item2", "item3"];
  res.json(list);
  console.log('Sent list of items');
});
```

I believe it should do the trick